# javascript how to quickly get total count of reports in employee array

Tags: javascript

I need to determine the total count of reports a manager has to specify the size of a square in a d3 treemap visualization. The data is a csv file with 209000 records and is formatted with these column headings: Employee, EmployeeID, and ManagerID.

The number I have to find includes direct and indirect reports--both people that have a manager id equal to the manager's employeeid and people who report to that lower level manager, and all reports down the corporate ladder.

```
var i, theLength, j, thejLength, k, thekLength;
var runningCount = 0;
function getReportCount(csvAll, employeeId, employee) {
  var csvAllModified = csvAll.filter(function(d) {
      return (d.ManagerID == employeeId);
  });
  runningCount+= csvAllModified.length;
    i=0
    theLength = csvAllModified.length;
    for(; i < theLength; i++){ // LOOP THROUGH ONE LEVEL REPORTS
        //GET REPORTS TWO LEVEL BELOW
        csvAllModified2 = csvAll.filter(function(d) {
          return (d.ManagerID == csvAllModified[i].EmployeeID);
        });     
        //managerIds.push(csvAllModified[i].EmployeeID);
        runningCount += csvAllModified2.length;
        j=0;
        thejLength = csvAllModified2.length;
        for(; j < thejLength; j++ ){
            //GET REPORTS THREE LEVELS BELOW
            csvAllModified3 = csvAll.filter(function(d) {
              return (d.ManagerID == csvAllModified2[j].EmployeeID);
            });
            runningCount += csvAllModified3.length;
            k=0;
            thekLength = csvAllModified3.length;
            for(; k < thekLength; k++) {
                //console.log('Employee name 3 levels below: ' +         csvAllModified3[k].Employee); 
                csvAllModified4 = csvAll.filter(function(d) {
                  return (d.ManagerID == csvAllModified3[k].EmployeeID);
                });
                runningCount += csvAllModified4.length;
            }
        }
    }
  return runningCount
}
```

**My question is**: how can I structure the code above so that it runs way more efficiently? At present it is taking a couple of minutes to run. And I have to add a couple more management layers to get the final total count.

Comment: Not sure why I got a down vote. This is a work problem I have and I need to find a solution if there is one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is slow because you loop over the big array several times. You want to find a way that you don't have to loop over the original array so many times. In this case, I would go csvAll.map(...) to create a hash you can directly reference a report in, so that you can go reports[employeeID] to select the report.
This way you only have to loop once to create the hashmap and the once to find the initial managerID. AFter that you can reference each report directly without having to loop again.